# 2 or more regex result PHP

Tags: php

granting i have a string

```
$string = "{orange,apple}{orange,mango}";
```

how do i get the words every after comma inside the brackets, which in this case apple and mango. after which place it in an array. thanks

Comment: Will there only ever be one comma inside the curlys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Escape the curly braces
2. Search for anything between the first curly bace and the first comma
3. Search for everything between that comma and the closing curly and capture it.

.

```
<?php
$string = "{orange,apple}{orange,mango}";
preg_match_all('~\{.*?,(.*?)\}~', $string, $secondwords);
print_r($secondwords[1]); 
?>
```

Comment: but what i want that the first result should be index 0, 2nd result should be index 1 and so on..

just like $secondwords = array("orange", "mango");

Comment: You could loop through the array, pull each value, and set it to another array. It currently is a multidimensional array though and you should be able to anything with $secondwords[1] that you would be able to do with a single array. If you need a single array here's the code... `foreach($secondwords[1] as $words) {
 $singlearray[] = $words;
}`